# Составить программу, которая находит сумму с пятого по двадцать первый элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, while

Дан ряд чисел: 100, 97, 94,…. Составьте программу, которая находит сумму с пятого по двадцать первый элемент. Должно выйти = 1088. Python

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(itertools.islice(range(100, 0, -3), 4, 21))
```